# How to shift certain rows in matrix using matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a Matrix `X= [A; B; C; D ; E; a; b; c; d; e ; f]` each alphabet represents a row matrix with three columns. I want a Matrix `X= [ A; a; b; c; B; d; e; f; C; D; E]` How to do it?

Comment: Use some actual sample values to demonstrate what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with indexing:

```
Y = X([1 6 7 8 2 9 10 11 3 4 5],:);
```

If you want something more dynamic, like generating the indexing vector `[1 6 7 8 2 9 10 11 3 4 5]` on the fly, please be more specific.

Comment: Ok..Crazy Rat(:-D nice user name).I'll give it a try.